# Undefined method in view – too nested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I work on an site where educational objectives are displayed by chapters. In one chapter the objectives have to be displayed in a special matrix therefore I came up with a special model (1 edu obj has only one row in disease_matrix).

```
class EducationalObjective < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chapter
  belongs_to :disease_matrix
end

class DiseaseMatrix < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :educational_objectives
end

class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :educational_objectives
end

ChaptersController
  def show
    @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
    @educational_objectives = @chapter.educational_objectives
  end
end
```

The objectives are displayed as I wish, but on the page with the matrix I don't know what to do:

```
<%= @chapter.title %>
<p><%= @chapter.description %></p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Objective</td>
      <td>Matrix AA</td>
      <td>Matrix BB</td>
      ...
      <td>Matrix XX</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @educational_objectives.each do |e| %>
    <tr>
     <td><%= e.name %></td>
     <td><%= e.disease_matrix.aa %>
     <td><%= e.disease_matrix.bb %>
     ...
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "disease_matrices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "educational_objective_id"
    t.integer "nklz_id"
    t.string "kardio"
    t.string "muscle"
    t.string "hormone"
    t.string "respi"
    t.string "blut"
    t.string "uro"
    t.string "verdauung"
    t.string "haut"
    t.string "sinne"
    t.string "nerven"
    t.string "op"
    t.string "therapeutika"
    t.string "infektion"
    t.string "notfall"
    t.string "gesundheit"
    t.string "dd"
    t.string "hygiene"
    t.string "compliance"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

The error is an undefined method "aa". Since I thought that the @educational_objectives are connected through the model to the DiseaseMatrix I just added them in the view. But it doesn't work.
Do I have to work on the Controller and add something like 
`@disease_matrix = ?!?`or what do I have to do?

Thanks in advance! And yes, I'm a newbie to rails.

Error message:
**undefined method `dd' for nil:NilClass**

Comment: Prevent the error by writing `e.disease_matrix.try(:aa)` and `e.disease_matrix.try(:bb)` if the error is `undefined method for NilClass`

Comment: Can you please share your schema.rb?

Comment: how does DiseaseMatrix model look?

Comment: Show complete error for further debugging

Comment: thanks! when I add .try(:aa) the error disappears but nothing  is displayed

Comment: mmh, maybe my problem is, that it's not a has_many but a has_one association. I'll play around with that.

Comment: This may be an issue to do with lazy loading of associations.  Try: `@educational_objectives = @chapter.educational_objectives.includes(:disease_matrix)` in your chapters controller.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set up a has_many :through relationship both ways between your chapters and disease matrices.

So instead of:

```
class DiseaseMatrix < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :educational_objectives
end
```

You want

```
class DiseaseMatrix < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :educational_objectives
  has_many :chapters, through: :educational_objectives
end
```

And vice versa on chapters.

You can read all about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great help and ideas.
My solution is as follows:

a) thinking more about the associations I figured out that it is a `has_one/belongs_to` association.

b) the hint with `.includes` got me to the right point in the manual where I got to `.join`.

After a bit of fiddling I came up with this which works as I whish:

```
class EducationalObjective < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chapter
  has_one :disease_matrix
end

class DiseaseMatrix < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :educational_objective
end

class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  #### no association to DiseaseMatrix necessary
end

ChaptersController
  def show
    @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
    @educational_objectives = @chapter.educational_objectives.joins(:disease_matrix)
  end
end
```

`<td><%= e.disease_matrix.kardio %></td>` displays now the stuff, I want it to present.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great help and ideas!
Here is my solution:

1st) thinking about the associations got me to the idea that it is a `has_one/belongs_to` association

2nd) the hint with `.include` brought me to the right place in the documentation from where I got to `.joins`

After fiddling a bit this is now my final code which displays everything as I want to:

```
class EducationalObjective < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chapter
  has_one :disease_matrix
end

class DiseaseMatrix < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :educational_objective
end

class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  ## no association to DiseaseMatrix needed
end

ChaptersController
  def show
    @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
    @educational_objectives = @chapter.educational_objectives.joins(:disease_matrix)
  end
end
```

`<td><%= e.disease_matrix.kardio %></td>` displays now the content of the db.

Thanks all for your help and time!